# how can I make a object detect if its value === another objects key and then get it

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

would anybody know of  a way how can I make a object detect if its value === another objects key and then get it

Lets say the object is called

AnswerString

```
let AnswerString ={
0: "B"
1: "x"
}
```

and the answers in in a few differnt objects But for simplicity sake lets say it is just one

lets call it M2060

```
var M2060 = {
  "B" : [
    " v-40  a20,10 0 0 1 0,20   a20,10 0 0 1 0,20 ",
   ],
   "x" : [
    "  l20,-20  l-10,10 l10,10 l-10,-10 l-10,-10 "
   ],
}
```

for context why its called M2060 is becuase that is the starting move to function for
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d
with that how could I get  0 and 1 to equal

```
AnswerString = {
0:  " v-40  a20,10 0 0 1 0,20   a20,10 0 0 1 0,20 ",
1: "  l20,-20  l-10,10 l10,10 l-10,-10 l-10,-10 "
}
```

or should I create another object with this values and how could I do that?
what I have been trying to do is

```
 if (M2060[answersString]) {
let soultion1 = M2060[answersString]); 
}
```

But I can see that does not work
EDIT:
So It looks like what I was missing was .Entries and map .

Comment: _"for context why its called M2060..."_ - That's not relevant for this question...

Comment: You've asked something like this before, but it still doesn't make any sense. For one thing, note that the `[ ]` operator always interprets the expression inside as a **string**, converting it to a string if necessary. Using an object therefore usually does not make sense for `[ ]`, certainly in this case.

Comment: [Working with objects - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Answer (score 0):

The OP seems to be aiming replace values in one object with values from another object, using the first values as keys.

```js
let AnswerString = {
  0: "B",
  1: "x"
};

let M2060 = {
  "B": [
    " v-40  a20,10 0 0 1 0,20   a20,10 0 0 1 0,20 "
  ],
  "x": [
    "  l20,-20  l-10,10 l10,10 l-10,-10 l-10,-10 "
  ]
};

let result = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(AnswerString).map(([k, v]) => [k, M2060[v]])
);

console.log(result);
```

`Object.entries()` returns an array arrays of key-value pairs.  This solution maps entries, returning the original object keys along with values looked up from the other object. `Object.fromEntries()` creates a new object from the (now transformed) array of key-values pairs.

Comment: I thought I was doing something wrong thank you .